# Tokbox - connection refused

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I tried to test the sample app in android opentok. I copied the API Key, session ID and token and when I lauch the app on Android 4.1 I get this log:

```
02-24 09:39:12.601 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest/lib/libopentok.so 0x41b06ee8
02-24 09:39:13.112 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest/lib/libopentok.so 0x41b06ee8
02-24 09:39:13.122 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-jni﹕ JNI_OnLoad called
02-24 09:39:13.172 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/WEBRTC﹕ JNI:SetAndroidAudioDeviceObjects
02-24 09:39:13.182 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-jni﹕ ***** OpenTok Android SDK : 20131112225450-otkit-android *****
02-24 09:39:13.392 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
02-24 09:39:13.482 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0 name= MPU-6050 Accelerometer delay= 66667 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*a.b-a8
02-24 09:39:13.482 17820-17870/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-jni﹕ ot_session_create
02-24 09:39:13.562 17820-17866/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-native﹕ [ERROR] jni/../src/ot_websvc_xml.c:636: errno: Connection refused ot_websvc_xml_request[*(ot_websvc_xml_req** ppwebsvc_xml_req)=0x58e71368]
02-24 09:39:13.562 17820-17866/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-native﹕ [ERROR] jni/../src/ot_websvc_client.c:1291: errno: Connection refused ot_websvc_client_create_ios_sdk_version_request[*(ot_websvc_client_ios_sdk_version_info** ppRequestInfo)=0x58e71348]
02-24 09:39:13.562 17820-17866/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/opentok-jni﹕ --------------------my_on_session_error 3 The session failed to connect.
02-24 09:39:13.662 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest I/demo-hello-world﹕ Session exception: The session failed to connect.
02-24 09:39:13.902 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-24 09:39:13.962 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-24 09:39:13.972 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-24 09:39:14.012 17820-17820/com.marcinmichalek.tokboxtest D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Anyone knows how to solve it? I enabled all needed permissions in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I had Internet access (wifi). It seems that it was a temporary server issue. I tried the same app some time later and it worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

do you have internet access on your android? Is the android device connected to cellular network of wifi? It seems that OpenTok has a hard time talking to the servers form these lines:

```
errno: Connection refused ot_websvc_xml_request[*(ot_websvc_xml_req** ppwebsvc_xml_req)=0x58e71368]

ERROR] jni/../src/ot_websvc_client.c:1291: errno: Connection refused ot_websvc_client_create_ios_sdk_version_request[*(ot_websvc_client_ios_sdk_version_info** ppRequestInfo)=0x58e71348]
```